# Can VSCode / Typescript do Type inference on plugin-modifed objects?

Tags: typescript, plugins, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I'm enjoying the developer ergonomics of VSCode and Typescript. A slight snag has occurred when I've applied a plugin to the `pouchdb` package:

```
import * as pouch from 'pouchdb-browser'
pouch.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));

const remoteDB: PouchDB.Database<PouchDB.Core.Encodable> = new pouch(
    'https://user.cloudant.com/databaseName',
    { skip_setup: true } // a param wanted by the plugin
);

// invoking a method added by the plugin:
remoteDB.signup('username','password', (err, resp) => {console.log(err)} );
```

The above code **works in the browser**, but my development experience is hindered because VSCode isn't recognizing the plugin-added methods:

[image: VSCode TS claiming 'signup' property doesn't exist]

Is this sort of type inference outside of VSCode's scope?

OF NOTE: There is no @types package for this package on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pouchdb-authentication is a 404. Is that the missing piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the documentation (https://pouchdb.com/api.html#plugins), the `plugin` method extends your `PouchDB.Database` object with whatever you pass to it.

As such in reality, if you use `pouch.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));`, then your database is no longer of type `PouchDB.Database<T>`; it is actually an extension of that interface. So the fact that VSCode is complaining is correct, as the type you have declared `remoteDB` to have does not have a `signup` method.

What you can do then is create your own interface for `remoteDB` that extends `PouchDB.Database<T>` with whatever methods and properties `pouchdb-authentication` adds; e.g.

```
interface PouchDBSignupPlugin<T> extends PouchDB.Database<T> {
    signup: (username: string, password: string, handler: (err: any, resp: any) => void) => any;
}
```

and use it as such:

```
const remoteDB = new pouch<PouchDB.Core.Encodable>(
    'https://user.cloudant.com/databaseName',
    { skip_setup: true } // a param wanted by the plugin
) as PouchDBSignupPlugin<PouchDB.Core.Encodable>;
```

Then you should find that VSCode and TypeScript will recognise a `signup` method on `remoteDB`.